# Sub Property in a TextBox

Tags: c#

Hi guys I am starting with C# (old Delphi developer) and I am having some difficult to increment some code on a new TextBox here is a simple exemplo what I want do

**Component TextBoxX from TextBox**

```
public class TextBoxX : TextBox
{
    public TextBoxX()
    {
    }
    public X XX { get; set; }
}
```

**Second Class just with 2 int fields I want show on the component**

```
public class X
{
    public int XXX { get; set; }
    public int YYY { get; set; } 
}
```

**I am looking for a result like that on the red box**

[image: I am looking for a result like that on the red box]

I did some tests using a "X : Component" but they come with some extra fields what I don't need.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: So you just want the drop down properties? Or is it something else?

Comment: Please don't post images of your code. It makes it much harder for us to help you.

Comment: the drop down properties I have some functions already in Delphi for some fields and need cross that for C# before start the rest

Comment: You need to add certain [Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/) to the properties of the `X` type, but I don't recall which ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem the main class you need use a "new X(this)"

```
public class TextBoxX : TextBox
{
    private X _valor;

    public X Field
    {
        get
        {
            if (_valor == null)
            {
                _valor = new X();
            }

            return _valor;
        }
    }
}
```

and on the children

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class X
{
    public int XXX { get; set; }
    public int YYY { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "X1"; //Or whatever you want shown when the property is collapsed
    }
}
```

Thank for help me

Answer (score 1):

You need to decorate your `XXX` class with a `TypeConverter`:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class XXX
{
    public int YYY { get; set; }
    public int ZZZ { get; set; }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "X1"; //Or whatever you want shown when the property is collapsed
    }
}
```

See [ExpandableObjectConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.expandableobjectconverter?view=netframework-4.7.2) on  Microsoft Docs.

Comment: do I need do something extra for it accept the values? I am inserting a value 123 and it always return to 0

Comment: I fixed that doing a repair on VS tks

Comment: Still do not working! just work when I write public struct xx but if I do that they don't save the value inserted!

Comment: Why are you using structs? Structs are value-based, so they won't work like that. Use a class.

Comment: I am using class but they don't show in the proprieties this is my big problem! I was checking the source of Form1 it create this.textBoxX1.XXX = null;